# Usar Firefox para rodar aplicação ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Quando vou debugar (F5), antes eu posso escolher o *browser* padrão. IE, Google  Chrome.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho instalado o Firefox, porém não está aparecendo para mim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode adicioná-lo manualmente.

Clique em "***Browse With...***", você verá esta tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clique em "***Add***" e procure pelo executável do Firefox clicando nas reticências

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora o Firefox vai aparecer na lista.

Comment: Consegui. como aqui na empresa, quando se instala um aplicativo ele vai pra um caminho na rede diferente. então fiz esse processo para adicionar manualmente.

Comment: Ótimo, sabia que era porque o caminho não era o padrão =) Aliás, não sei se você já sabe, mas sempre pode escolher a resposta que mais te ajudou como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da resposta. Eu percebi que você tem várias respostas e nenhuma delas tem resposta selecionada, então achei pertinente avisar.

Answer (score 1):

Se fizeres Browse With, o Firefox não aparece? Se aparece, tenta colocá-lo como default, para ver se aparece nessa lista.